# Calling a method every time instance of singleton is accessed

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, singleton

I am using a singleton class in my code which is primarily responsible of communicating with a device.

One of the major function in the class is ConnectToDevice() there is also another method called IsPhoneConnected() in the library.

so basically before any other method is called a simple check would be to connect the device IF it is not already connected. So either every method or every time a client application calls my library, someone is responsible of writting follwoing code

```
(!IsPhoneConnected())
{
   ConnectToDevice() 
    return IsPhoneConnected() // If phone is not connected, try to connect, if still not connected then return false.
}
```

I do not want to write this logic again and again. I want the class to take care of this without having to call this piece of code over and over.

any ideas?

Comment: A command pattern? Not really clear what you're looking for here...

Comment: Can;t you just put `IsPhoneConnected()` inside `ConnectToDevice()` in the singleton?

Comment: YEs I can. But still ConnectToDevice() will be called on every function, correct? I want to minimize having to call the ConnectToDevice()

Comment: If any given function *requires* the phone to be connected, surely it must be *interacting* with the singleton connection class in some way already? In that case, whatever code is interacting with the phone within the singleton can call ConnectToDevice() if it's not connected already.

Answer (score 2):

If any given function *requires* the phone to be connected, it must be *interacting* with the singleton connection class in some way already.

In that case, whatever code is interacting with the phone within the singleton can call ConnectToDevice() if it's not connected already.

However, if you really want to execute a method *every time* a set functions are called without having to explicitly call each time, then what you're talking about is **aspect oriented programming**.

This paradigm isn't native to C#, but can be simulated using tools like   [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/).

For a good tutorial on how to use PostSharp to add aspects to your code, have a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/337564/Aspect-Oriented-Programming-Using-Csharp-and-PostS) CodeProject article.

You could end up with something like:

```
[PhoneConnectedAspect]
private void DoStuffWithPhone
{
     // your code here
}
```

Any method tagged with that attribute could automatically call the ConnectToDevice() method, for example.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments. They are very helpful. However, Is there anyway to [PhoneConnectedAspect] at the class level rather than method level so that compiler knows that this aspect is getting injected for each method for the class?

Answer (score 1):

Like Baldrick says: it sounds a bit like aspect oriented programming.

Nevertheless, if calling any method on your library requires the phone to be connected, I would embed the ConnectToDevice in the library itself. E.g. just embed it in every method of your library that requires to phone to be connected.

AOP would be better, but this emulates it.